# SQL, BigQuery - completing missing values with other part of rows

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase data exported to BigQuery (data contains events data coming from mobile application). I've made an update to the application and new parameter is being reported. Unfortunately, not all users have the latest version of app. This is why I have rows with that parameter as well as rows without it.

In `event_params` I have something like:

```
| No | contentId | contentName         |
|----|-----------|---------------------|
| 1  | abc       | (parameter missing) |
| 2  | abc       | Name of ABC         |
| 3  | cde       | Name of CDE         |
| 4  | efg       | Name of EFG         |
| 5  | abc       | (parameter missing) |
| 6  | cde       | Name of CDE         |
```

Now, when I query that table and I specify (using UNNEST) that I need `contentName` parameter, I don't get rows where that parameter is missing.
I have query:

```
SELECT
  ep.value.string_value as ContentID,
  ep2.value.string_value as ContentName,
  COUNT(1) as `Count`
FROM
  `mydataset.mytable.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) as ep,
  UNNEST(event_params) as ep2
WHERE 
  event_name="my_event_name" AND
  ep.key="contentID" AND
  ep2.key="contentName"
GROUP BY 1,2
```

and I get:

```
| No | contentId | contentName | Count |
|----|-----------|-------------|-------|
| 1  | abc       | Name of ABC | 1     |
| 2  | cde       | Name of CDE | 2     |
| 3  | efg       | Name of EFG | 1     |
```

However, I would like to get:

```
| No | contentId | contentName | Count |
|----|-----------|-------------|-------|
| 1  | abc       | Name of ABC | 3     |
| 2  | cde       | Name of CDE | 2     |
| 3  | efg       | Name of EFG | 1     |
```

I want to complete somehow rows with missing `contentName` parameters using values from other rows with the same `contentId` (we can assume that each contentId has the same, constant contentName)

How can I achieve it? I thougt about SELF JOIN, but it's rather not recommended by BigQuery.

Comment: my understanding that your real ask is in second from last paragraph of your post - you should present example of your input data and desired output - showing us your intermediate troubleshooting data - doesn't help much us to help you - but still valuable as it gives some extra info - but main info is still missing

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I don't understand what more do you expect. I've already posted my event_params content, my query, my desired output and the output I'm getting with my current query - everything you mentioned :)

Comment: How those examples support your following statement "I want to complete somehow rows with missing contentName parameters using values from other rows with the same contentId"? I don't see how!

Comment: Each row of table represents one event from application. Each row has event_params array. Some of that rows contains contentName parameter in event_params and some of that rows contains event_params without contentName, but all of rows contain contentId parameter.
I want to calculate all rows (with and without contentName) - I could just query for contentID (all rows contain it), but I need also contentName value - this is why I need to get it from rows which contains both of those parameters.

Comment: My understanding of UNNEST, event_params and analyzing those data comes from: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-the-unnest-function-in-bigquery-to-analyze-event-parameters-in-analytics-fb828f890b42

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Gordon can be slightly modified in order to achieve what you intend:

```
SELECT contentId.value.string_value as ContentID,
       MAX(contentName.value.string_value) as ContentName,
       COUNT(1) as `Count`
FROM `mydataset.mytable.events_*` e LEFT JOIN
      UNNEST(e.event_params) as contentId
      ON contentId.key = 'contentID' LEFT JOIN
      UNNEST(e.event_params) contentName
      ON contentName.key = 'contentName'
WHERE e.event_name = 'my_event_name'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note that I am grouping only by the ContentID and I am aggregating the ContentNames using MAX, which ignores null values.

I have recreated your example table and it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can update the table so that you fill the nulls and then make your query

[1]

```
UPDATE `your_project.your_dataset.your_table` t_incomplete
SET t_incomplete.contentName = t_complete.contentName
FROM `your_project.your_dataset.your_table` t_complete
WHERE t_incomplete.contentId = t_complete.contentId
AND t_complete.contentName IS NOT NULL
```

I am not sure how will this work with nested tables but you can always

1. UPDATE UNNESTING
2. UPDATE WITH QUERY [1]
3. UPDATE NESTING

You can picture the idea behind with this sample CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE  `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
(
  id INT64,
  nullable STRING
);

INSERT INTO `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
VALUES (1, 'foo');

INSERT INTO `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
VALUES (1, null);

INSERT INTO `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
VALUES (2, 'lel');

INSERT INTO `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
VALUES (1, null);

INSERT INTO `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table`
VALUES (2, null);
```

and QUERY[2]

```
UPDATE `your_project.your_dataset.sample_table` t_incomplete

SET t_incomplete.nullable = t_complete.nullable
FROM `wave27-sellbytel-aalbesa.trial_dataset.with_and_update` t_complete
WHERE t_incomplete.id = t_complete.id
AND t_complete.nullable IS NOT NULL
```

This way you actually give the corresponding value to the cell and you can run your query without worries. I hope this works!

Comment: Unfurtunately, updating table is not an option

Answer (score -2):

Do you just need an `OR` condition?

```
WHERE event_name = 'my_event_name' AND
      ep.key = 'contentID' AND
      (ep2.key = 'contentName' OR ep2.key IS NULL)
```

EDIT:

I think you need `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT contentId.value.string_value as ContentID,
       contentName.value.string_value as ContentName,
       COUNT(1) as `Count`
FROM `mydataset.mytable.events_*` e LEFT JOIN
      UNNEST(e.event_params) as contentId
      ON contentId.key = 'contentID' LEFT JOIN
      UNNEST(e.event_params) contentName
      ON contentName.key = 'contentName'
WHERE e.event_name = 'my_event_name'
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Note:  This should preserve the counts you want but might result in extra rows in the result set.

Comment: No, with your query I'm getting the same results as with my query. Using `(ep2.key="contentName" OR ep2.key IS NULL)` doesn't change anything - rows without `contentName` parameter are not being calculated.

Comment: regarding updated answer - with that I'm gettting rows counts duplicated (with proper contentName and with contentName=null). I want each contentId to show up just once - with proper contentName (taken from rows, which contains both of that parameters).